# Kendo UI Combo Box Reset Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I'm using the Kendo UI ComboBoxes in cascade mode to build up a filter that I wish to apply.

How do I clear/reset the value of a Kendo UI ComboBox?

I've tried:

```
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").val('');
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").select('');
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").select(null);
```

all to no avail. The project is an MVC4 app using the Razor engine and the code is basically the same as the [Kendo UI example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/cascadingcombobox.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to use `select` the you need to provide the index of the option. Otherwise use [`text`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#methods-text)

```
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").text('');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/4aHbH/

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted. Thank you for taking the extra time to provide the example.

Comment: I have been running into bugginess in the Kendo ComboBox where it sometimes stops responding properly to ".value(text/value)" and ".select(1)" but it still responds to ".text('xx')". (perfectly normal api calls which normally work stop working) I set the value on the input before constructing the widget now which always works.

Comment: This doesn't work.. try this.. select first value.. and click on reset. now, again select first value cascade box does not popup

Answer (score 3):

I had to create my custom clear function extending involved Kendo UI controls like the following:

```
kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn.clear = kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn.clear = function () {
    if (!!this.text) {
        this.text("");
    }
    if (!!this.value) {
        this.value(null);
    }
    this._prev = this.oldIndex = this._old = this._last = undefined;
};
```

Then you can call `$("mycontrol").data("kendoAutoComplete").clear();` to clear the control and have the change handler invoked when doing the following: select an item, clear and select again the previous item.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found these options below seem to work to reset the kendo combo box. You can run `$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").select()` after trying two below and you should see a value returned of -1, indicating its reset.

```
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").value('')
$('#comboBox').data().kendoComboBox.value('')
$("#comboBox").data("kendoComboBox").select(-1)
$('#comboBox').data().kendoComboBox.select(-1)
```